# Can I claim the tax back from my lawyer's fee?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, new-jersey

I received a settlement from a car accident of 285000.
I have a personal GST number, so can I claim the tax from my lawyer's 30% fee which seems high?
I haven't worked since this accident in 2012. I had to be helicoptered from accident site.

Comment: I assume you are in the US since you put a "new jersey" tag

Comment: What is a GST number?

Comment: @littleadv Why would use assume that? "GST number" is not a US term. It's used in the UK, Canada, and India (and maybe other countries) in the context of handling VAT.

Comment: The OP tagged the question as "new jersey". I suspect the gst number means it's some kind of scam

Comment: You should have considered whether the lawyer's fee was acceptable before hiring them rather than complaining afterward. Though realistically, hiring a competent lawyer for this sort of claim *IS* almost always expensive; that's just the way the system works.

Answer (score 2):

Attorney fees for insurance and liability claims are not tax deductible in the US.

Comment: But the insurance payout itself generally wouldn't be taxable income in the United States, would it?

Comment: @jeffronicus depending on what the payout is. It may be taxable.